# Best way to match(search) a URL in a list in C (implementing whitelist or blacklist)?

Tags: c, string, list, hash, match

I'm writing a proxy server. It applies different rules to websites that match in lists. For example, we can block List A and use another proxy to fetch content for List B.

For example, List A:

```
.google.com
blogger.com
sourceforge.net
ytimg.com
http://media-cache-*.pinterest.com/*
images-amazon.com
*.amazonaws.com
twitter.com
fbcdn.net
google-analytics.com
staticflickr.com
```

List B:

```
ytimg.com
youtube.com
```

Currently, the match function is:

```
struct proxy_t *
match_list(char *url) {
  // 2KB line should be enough
  char buf[2048];
  int pos = 0, size;

  struct acllist *al = config->acl_h;
  struct acl *node = al->data; 

  while (node != NULL) { // iterate list
    pos = 0; // position in list file

    size = strlen(node->data); // node->data holds a URL list

    while (1) { // iterate each line in list

      readline(buf, node->data, &pos, size);

      if (buf[0] == 0) break;

      if (strcasestr(url, buf) != NULL 
      || !fnmatch(buf, url, FNM_CASEFOLD)) {

          return node->proxy;
      }
    }
    node = node->next;
  }


  printf("Not Matched\n");

  return config->default_proxy;
}
```

That is, iterate the two list files, read line by line, use **strcasestr** and **fnmatch** to match a single URL.

It works fine. But if the lists get larger and more, say 10,000 lines per list and 5 lists, I suppose it won't be an efficient solution since it is an O(N) algorithm.

I'm thinking about adding a hit counter to each match line. By ordering the match lines it may reduce the average search length. Like this:

```
.google.com|150
blogger.com|76
sourceforge.net|43
ytimg.com|22
```

Is there any other ideas on it?

Comment: It's not about parsing URL. It's about how to efficiently match a URL list.

Comment: You might want to look into hash-tables to store the URLs, or some kind of search tree.

Comment: Thank you, everyone. I finally sort it out. No matter using hash table or search tree, do it with its domain(xxx.xx). Once we find the node(also head of a linked list), iterate the list and match it with **fnmatch** and **strstr**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways you could go to improve performance.

**1**

First way is order the URL lists in some way and therefore you can optimize searching in it.
[Quicksort](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~bobh/367/SORTING.html#quick) is fastest algorithm out there.

[Bubble sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort) is easier to implement.

Then you can use [binary search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm) to search in the list.
Binary search has logarithmic performance while your loop has linear, therefore it will be significantly faster on large lists.

**2**

If your lists of URLs are static, you can use special tool called [flex](https://github.com/westes/flex), which enables you to parse the string just by reading it.

This also means, then when some of your URL lists is updated, you have to write new code for parsing or create code generator.

This is much more effective way of parsing, then any kind of sorting, because it only need N steps, when N is the length of URL you are parsing, therefore it doesn't matter how long your list is, as long as you can write correct scanner for inputs.